# Parent & Child titles on WordPress Custom Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, title

I have a website layout (Custom Wordpress theme), where in title the hierarchy should be

**Child page / Parent page / Company name**

..so for example like: Accounting / Services / Company name

And on the Parent page it should go on `<h1>` tag for example:

Services / Accounting

How do I get such to work? Without plugins.

Currently I have on `<title>` the following code:

```
<?php wp_title(' '); ?><?php if(wp_title(' ', false)) { echo ' / '; } ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

That makes it go like Services / Company name, but no Child page title there.

On content.php I have just the following:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?> / </h1>
```

How I make the title go like following that hierarchy?